# Trigger AS3 method with PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm currently writing a webcam program (like in Facebook's profile picture) in AS3 and I would like to be able to save the drawn picture to the server when clicking a button on my site. Is there any way of doing this? Do I need to create a socket or is there an easier way of doing it?

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flash plugin runs on the client, the PHP script runs on the server. You always have to establish some kind of remote connection between the two.  Using a client side button to start a server side script that triggers a client side function to send data to the server seems quite unpractical, but it is certainly possible.

The way I see it, there are basically four ways to implement the functionality you want:

1. When the button is pressed, use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call a Flash method and retrieve the image data as ByteArray via JavaScript, *then* connect to your PHP script via AJAX.
2. Use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to trigger a Flash method that connects directly to the PHP script and sends the image data as ByteArray via URLLoader (without AJAX).
3. Establish a socket connection from the Flash content, then use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) and JavaScript to trigger a Flash method, which then sends the image through the socket.
4. Establish a socket connection from the Flash content, then add an event listener to listen to an event that is sent from the server when the button is pressed, and trigger a Flash method that then sends the image to the server.

In addition to the client-server-client problem I mentioned above, I would strongly advise against socket connections, unless you have highly interactive or time critical content, such as chats or multiplayer games (you bind your server's resources during the entire time a user is on the page).  If all you need is to create a single connection to send the data, use either 1. or 2.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely look into option 1 and 2!

Comment: @weltraumpirat You may have some terminology (or concept - probably not concept) issues in you answer. You don't *connect* to a PHP script, you make a request to it. That is why you shouldn't even think of using sockets here... It may be possible, but it makes no sense in a HTTP environment. Stick witih POST. Also why make the request from JS when you have your data in Flash? He should definitively choose the second option.

Comment: @Alin: I won't get into splitting hairs, but sure, you CONNECT to the web server, which runs the script, when you send a HTTP request.  There is, however, absolutely nothing wrong with creating a socket connection to a PHP script NOT using HTTP.  See this simple chat room tutorial: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash8/php5sockets_flash8.htm

Comment: Also, if the button is not within Flash, he will have to use JavaScript to trigger the Flash method.  Then perhaps an AJAX script will send the data to the server, and remove the Flash plugin to display the picture upon successful upload.  Why is that not an option?

Comment: @weltraumpirat Well of course they are all options that can be made to work one way or another. But I think you should always choose the most straightforward way (sockets are overkill for this). In my opinion the second option should be a clear winner. But as you said, there's no point in splitting hairs, so I'll leave it at this. Good luck, Pierre Wahlgren!

Comment: @Alin: I would probably make the same decision, unless the use case is similar to what I wrote last.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and passing an [URLRequest](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) to its [load](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#load%28%29) method. Just set set the request method to `POST` and put what you want to upload inside `data`.

If you want examples just search using the two class names above as keywords.

On the server side (the PHP script, that is) you need to expect that sent data and save it on the server. Also returning a succeeded/failed message would make sense.

Good luck,
Alin

Comment: I think you misunderstood me :-) I want to upload the image when I press a HTML button on my site. I have tried using URLLoader and URLRequest, but they only load what's in the PHP file at the moment, and are not waiting for new contents. What I need is more of a push solution. Button -> Javascript -> PHP -> AS3 -> Save Image.

Comment: @Pierre Wahlgren A PHP file is a dynamic script. If you want to save the image, you need to write a custom PHP script that expects some data to be uploaded and saves it on the server. Maybe your question should be about the PHP part? Also you may mean *Flash button*, because if it's a HTML button you will need an extra connection between JavaScript and Flash.

Comment: No I mean a HTML button. Why would I need an extra connection between JavaScript and Flash? I can just bind a click event to the button with JavaScript and send an AJAX request to PHP. What I do not know is how PHP can trigger an AS3 method, whenever I want it to.

Comment: @Pierre "connection between JavaScript and Flash" = ExternalInterface. Triggering an action from PHP to AS3 may be possible with sockets, but you shouldn't need to do that. A simple data upload should have to do. After all we're talking about a web environment so HTTP should be the weapon of choice.

Comment: ExternalInterface does exactly what I want. :-)